# Angular select remember when move through views

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want that my option in selection stay selected when i move through views and go back.

**Here is view:**

```
<select ng-model="getseason" class="form-control" ng-options="season  as 'Season '+ season + '/' + seasonaddone(season) for season in seasons">
```

**Here is controller:**

```
$scope.seasons = [2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005];

$scope.getseason = $scope.seasons[0];

$scope.$watch('getseason',function(){

    var url = 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/?season=' +   $scope.getseason;

    apiDataService.GetData(url).then( function( data) { 

        $scope.leagues =  data;

    });

});
```

I know when i go back from other view, this controller load again and set value to `season[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service and store this value there. **Each services is only instatiated once per application load**, so if you store a value there, it won't dissapear after route changes. Btw. this can be also a good place to store your model (i.e. seasons array). Example implemenation:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, seasonHelper) {

    $scope.getseason = seasonHelper.getseason;
    $scope.$watch('getseason', function(){
         seasonHelper.getseason = $scope.getseason;
         ...
    });

})
.service('seasonHelper', function () {

    this.seasons = [2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005];
    this.getseason = this.seasons[0];

});
```